# Html Dropdown list On Change function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have this dropdown list

```
 @Html.DropDownList("orderPosted", orderList, new { data_native_menu = "false", data_options_prefix = "Insert at Position: ", data_mini = "true" })
```

and the script to update #itemPosition to pass it to the controller

```
   @Html.Hidden("itemPosition")

        <script>$("#itemPosition").val($("#orderPosted option:selected").text());

       $(function () {
                $("#orderPosted").on("change", function () {
                    $("#itemPosition").val($("option:selected", this).text());
                });

            })
        </script>
```

It will assign the text to #itemPosition when the page loads, but the 'On Change' function is not working. What is wrong with the way I have this formatted.

Comment: You have `$("itemPosition")` when it should be `$("#itemPosition")`

Comment: Thank you. It still does not work with the change.

Comment: One problem appears to be that the 'selected' property is not updating when another option is chosen. Somehow, the correct value from the dropdown list is being passed to the controller, but not the text of the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example, you can find out what you are doing wrong by comparing it with your code:

```js
function getSelected(el) {
  var value = el.val();
  var text = el.find("option").filter(":selected").text();
  $("#page-one pre").text("Selected: "+value+" - "+text);  
}

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-one", function() {
  getSelected($("#select-custom-1"));
  $("#select-custom-1").change(function() {
    getSelected($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content" role="main">
      <select name="select-custom-1" id="select-custom-1" data-native-menu="false">
        <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
        <option selected value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
        <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
        <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
      </select>
      <pre></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

BTW, yes you are right, the `selected` **attribute** won't be updated, but by using the filter as above, you will get (and can post back) the selected option(s) text as expected.

Comment: I think your example may lead to the correct answer, but we were able to find a workaround using the value passed to the controller.

Comment: @DanielMitchell: THX for your feedback, if you are dealing with JQM, don't miss this great post: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events – What, Why, Where, When & How?](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)